# How to insert into specific columns of a database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

The problem is am getting an exception error that says data mismatch in the external database when i try to insert

I have a customer booking table with booking id ...pk  as auto number, customer.... fk and date in as datetime
Booking id is auto increment so i don't need to insert anything

What i want to achieve is to insert into customer_id and date in thats all but i keep getting the data mismatch and number of query valuesis not the same as destination fields

So what is the right way to put this

```
using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString())) {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into customer_booking  ([customer_id],[date_in]) values (?,?)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", txtusername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_in", dtdate_in);
    cmd.Connection = myCon;
    myCon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("your booking was successful ", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Add a Tag that specifies what type of database you're working with, post the table definition (Columns and their Type) and the value assigned to `dtdate_in` -- Possibly, avoid `AddWithValue()` -- OleDbCommand is also disposable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `cmd.Parameters.add('...')` method as follow :

```
using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ToString())) {
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into customer_booking  ([customer_id],[date_in]) values (@customer_id,@date_in)";
///* Set your column dataType*/
cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.VarChar , 50).Value = txtusername.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_in", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtdate_in; 
cmd.Connection = myCon;
myCon.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("your booking was successful ", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Does the order of the query values matter ? Or they can be in an order

Comment: nop,in this way is not matter,show me your error

Comment: Data type mismatch in Criteria expression , i believe certain data is being entered in the booking _id which is a number in my case and it auto increments

Comment: yeah,you should set your dataType ,i wrote sample dataType,your dataType must be equal with column dataType in sql

Comment: I have tried it but configuration manager doesn't exist in the context
Even if i add using system configuration

Comment: add reference System.Configuration

Comment: Sorry to bother you but am kinda new to this way of inserting queey , now i have object reference set to null on the first line which you just gave me